# Deployment issue of an web application using MSDeploy command

Tags: msdeploy

I have a web application and I am trying to deploy it on a webserver using MSDeploy.exe (Web Deploy 2)

I have tried 4 scenarios:

1. Through VS2010 Publish method with following settings:

   Publish Method: Web Deploy

   Service Url: https://MyServerName:8172/MsDeploy.axd

   Site/application: MyWebSiteName

   Allow untrusted: checked

   Username: MyUsername

   Password: MyPassword

   This method works just fine. 

   On MyServerName machine I have Web Management Service running; I have a website MyWebSiteName, an application MyWebAppName and MyUserName is an IIS Manager for it.
2. Through VS2010 Publish method with following settings:

   Publish Method: Web Deploy

   Service Url: https://MyServerName:8172/MsDeploy.axd

   Site/application: MyWebSiteName/MyWebAppName

   Allow untrusted: checked

   Username: MyUsername

   Password: MyPassword

   This method works just fine.
3. Through MSDeploy.exe command line (within a Powershell script)

   $Source = "contentPath='...._PublishedWebsites\MyWebApp'"

   $Destination = "contentPath=MyWebSiteName,computerName='https://fc-wapps-trial:8172/MsDeploy.axd?Site=WebSiteTest',Username=MyUsername,Password=MyPassword,AuthType=basic"

   MSDeploy -verb:sync -source:$Source -dest:$Destination -allowUntrusted

   This method also works fine.
4. Through MSDeploy.exe command line (within a Powershell script)

   $Source = "contentPath='...._PublishedWebsites\MyWebApp'"

   $Destination = "iisApp=MyWebSiteName/MyWebAppName,computerName='https://fc-wapps-trial:8172/MsDeploy.axd?Site=WebSiteTest/MyWebAppName',Username=MyUsername,Password=MyPassword,AuthType=basic"

   MSDeploy -verb:sync -source:$Source -dest:$Destination -allowUntrusted

   This method doesn't work. I am getting the following error.

   Error Code: ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED

   More Information: Connected to the destination computer ("MyServerName") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site.

   Error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

I was looking at what is the actuall MSDeploy command that the method 2 uses and I got something like:

msdeploy.exe

-source:manifest='...\MyWebApp.SourceManifest.xml' 

-dest:auto,ComputerName='https://MyServerName:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=WebSiteTest',UserName='MyUsername',Password='MyPassword',IncludeAcls='False',AuthType='Basic' 

-verb:sync 

-disableLink:AppPoolExtension 

-disableLink:ContentExtension 

-disableLink:CertificateExtension 

-skip:objectname='dirPath',absolutepath='...\App_Data$' 

-setParam:kind='ProviderPath',scope='IisApp',match='^...\PackageTmp$',value=WebSiteTest/WebAppTest 

-setParam:kind='ProviderPath',scope='setAcl',match='^..\PackageTmp$',value=WebSiteTest/WebAppTest 

-allowUntrusted 

-retryAttempts=2 

Now this doesn't seem to be anything close to what I am using in method 4. I tried running it myself without success, but I assume I wasn't able to properly re-create all those parameters.

So my questions are: 

- What I am doing wrong in method 4?

- How can I deploy a web application as a website application in IIS7 using MSDeploy.exe command

Thanks in advance for your help

Iulian

Comment: How did you accomplish "... looking at what is the actuall MSDeploy command that the method 2 uses"?

Comment: I think you can find the answer [here](http://sedodream.com/2010/11/04/WebDeployHowToSeeTheCommandExecutedInVisualStudioDuringPublish.aspx). Well he says MS uses MSDeploy Object Model by default when publishing but you can change that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into the same issue as you did.  I solved it by only use site name in 
https://computername:8172/msdeploy.axd?site={websitenameonly}.  Then set your webapplication path in the parameter using -setParam IIS Web Application Name= {your web application name here} or use a parameter file.  And everything deployed fine.

It seems that the site querystring value is required to authorize the request only.  I haven't find any definitive documentation from MS on any other querystring parameters that might solve this.  But I actually tested 2 cases.  1) Deploying to a web site in IIS 7.5, this parameter is required.  2) Deploying to a web application under a web site, this parameter is actually optional, but if you want to include it, then it has to be a root site.

You actually answered your own question here just probably didn't realize it.

Comment: I appologize for marking it aa a valid answer with such delay!

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Management Service Delegation (if you haven't already). Click on the main site in IIS Manager to bring up all Web Deploy options in the center panel. At the bottom (past ASP.NET, IIS, etc), under Management, you should see several options, including "Management Service Delegation".

Under this configuration is all the Provider contexts you might run into and the paths/types you might use them against (and under what usernames, etc... can get pretty granular).

Make very sure that the provider type you're trying to communicate under (iisApp, contentPath, etc) is not only listed, but has the path/scope you require and that you're operating under permissions that have been cleared.

Remember: you don't have to use an administrator-type user if delegation is set up correctly. AND you've gone to the applicable site's IIS Manager Permissions and added an Allowed User, like Domain\User, or even a custom IIS Manager User.